# Running selective unit tests with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have just started working on an existing project that has existing unit tests. The unit tests take over a minute to build and run.

Ia there a way to selectively run unit tests such that i can run my own unit tests but no unit tests that was made in the past?

-Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using [Ignore] instead of [Test] as an attribute of the tests you don't want to run?

Comment: Hmm.. if i end up having to change the test code, i might as well just remove the the [TestMethod()] attribute and that'll prevent the unit tests from running

Comment: I'm using ReSharper with VS2008 currently, and I know that in there you can select which tests you want to include on a session and which not, but IDK if there's a way to make it remember the selected tests between sessions... in here is mandatory to run all of them for any build. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.